# Copy folder to another folder in VBA

Tags: vba, directory, path, copy, filesystemobject

I want to copy one folder among many folders and paste it to another location. How can I achieve this using VBA?

I am using the below code but it copies all the folders and save it. I just want to copy one folder.

```
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath1, Destination:=ToPath
```

*FromPath1* has many folders. Say *a,b,c,d,e*. I just want to copy *a* and save it to *ToPath*.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `FromPath1`. For example, instead of "C:\Temp" use "C:\Temp\a"